# Hadoop - Help required to understand the processing steps

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have compressed file and it contains 8 xml files of size 5-10kb. I took this data for testing purpose. I wrote one map only program to uncompress the compressed file. I `wrote program in MR2 and using Hadoop 2.7.1 in psuedo distributed mode`. I start the cluster using `sbin/start-dfs.sh` command. I am able to see the decompressed output in the file system within few seconds but the processing continues for next 5-6 minutes. I don't know why?

[image]

MR program uncompressed the files till this stage and I can view / download those files.

[image]

Not able to understand what processing my mapreduce program is doing here. I `am using MR2 API in my code and why it is using MR1 API(mapred) here?` Situation become worse when I have 128mb of zipped files and it uncompressed in 5-10 mins and rest of the time it is busy in doing some other tasks.

The performance I am getting in unacceptable and need to understand what processing hadoop does in 2nd screen shot.

Please help me to understand whether it is installation issue, my program issue or any other issue?

Comment: Can you share the code snippet you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an config issue and I am resolve this with change in `mapred-site.xml` file.

```
<configuration>
<property>  
 <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>  
 <value>yarn</value>  
 </property>
</configuration>
```